# ffmpeg drawbox heigth from drawtext

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, drawtext

I want to create a background for my text in my video, I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]drawtext=font='arial.ttf': text='This is text line 1':x=(w-tw)/2:y=((h-text_h)/2)-(text_h): fontsize=55: fontcolor=red,drawbox=y=(h/2):color=black@0.4:width=iw:height=40:t=max" out.mp4
```

but I do not know how to get the text height for the drawbox. I tried the box property for drawtext but this just have the width of the text and I want the width of the video. Is there a way to get the height of the text and use in the height property of the drawbox?

Thanks so much

Comment: If you find answer, please answer below. It would be great help :)